# Electrical Ceiling Lights: Torsion vs Friction Clips Installation Differences

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling, wire

Is there any difference between Using Torsion springs vs Friction clips in installing ceiling lights? I am trying to understand the advantages/differences between the two methods.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdJlo5RVZCw

[image]

Halo Eaton Lights

Answer (score 5):

Whether you use the torsion springs or friction clips depends entirely on the type of housing you're mounting the trim plate on. If the housing has a spring bracket in it like the picture below, you would use the torsion springs. If there is no spring bracket, only a few holes or slots for a straight spring, then you'd use the friction clips to secure the trim plate to the housing.

I like the torsion springs. they do a better job of hugging the ceiling. If there's a little play in the mounting of the housing, the friction clips are harder to push up for a tight fit. Plus they are easier to pull down and adjust if necessary

(Note: picture from utube)

[image]

Comment: so its depends on the housing, whats better durability, or general advantage wise? I can choose my housing depending on the answer

Comment: I like the torsion springs. they do a better job of hugging the ceiling.  If there's a little play in the mounting of the housing, the friction clips are harder to push up for a tight fit.  Plus they are easier to pull down and adjust if necessary.

Comment: Given the opportunity to choose, torsion springs for sure (though these days there are also "junction box mount" LED lights that save the cost of a housing at all, if you are still in the "shopping" phase.)